# SKNode run action synchronously in Swift 4

Tags: swift

Does anyone know how to make the `mynode.run()` in synchronously

Here is my snippet:

```
func myfunc(){
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.1, duration: 2.0)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)])

    mynode.run(sequence, completion:{
        print("act1 => act2 => completion")
    })
}
```

`mynode.run(..)` is running in asynchronously by default. However I want to change it to 
run in synchronously.

For example: 
I did not want "`myfunc(..)`" return untile 
`completion:{...}` is called

I don't mind the "synch code" will block my main thread

What I have tried so far, but I can not make the `mynode.run(..)` sychnocarpously.

I have used DispatchGroup() as follow

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
myfunc(..)
dispatchGroup.leave() 

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
   ... 
}
```

Comment: ***I don't mind the "synch code" will block my main thread*** Do mind. In sprite kit games blocking means all sprites and system provided effects would freeze there. Or you should better describe why you can accept an app which freezes.

Comment: I mean the thread in the update(..),  my simple question. is it possible to make the completion{..} code synch instead of async so that myfunc will not return untile completion:{} finish